# Convert Google Map to Image without static image api

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps

I am working on a project in which I need high resolution images from google maps to plug into a canvas as the background. I know that the static image api doesn't allow you to get the 45 degree aerial shots that are much higher fidelity than regular satellite images. I need high fidelity images, and thus I need the 45 degree aerial shots and the static image api is out. Are there other approaches to saving google maps images with javascript? I have about a 800X500 embedded map that users will use to find an exact location they want to isolate and then I need to grab an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could [use the canvas to rasterize the output of an embedded map out to a jpg](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but it seems likely that this sort of thing would be forbidden by Google Maps' Terms of Service.  To wit:

> You may not access the maps or satellite images through any mechanism besides the Google Maps APIs (such as the creation of your own mapping API or the use of a bulk tile download script)

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_tiles

Comment: Ya, I'm not sure there is a way to do it without the static api.. Stupid Google! Haha.